# Querying Temporal Tables

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to query temporal tables, so that I can view how the tables changed by day?

I have not worked with temporal tables before, so what I'm doing now is using the for `system_time` in a bunch of queries by date. I know there has to be a better way.

Comment: You have read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15) right?

Comment: Was there a specific part of the Temporal Tables documentation on the Microsoft site that was unclear? The examples they write for you seem pretty clear

Comment: I don't have the docs, i'll take a look. all I want to do, is see how the data is changing over time, our developers, assure me that this is used now instead of a SCD. But I can't figure out how to compare dates...

Comment: So, here's what i'm trying to get as outcome at the very least, I know that on 2/14 I had 4,000 rows, but on 2/15 I had 9,000, I would like to run a query that shows how many records per day by date

Comment: So having read the docs, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I can't figure out the query to write to do this comparrision.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, they refer to columns called `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` (they can be called anything you want, but I'll be using those names in this discussion). On insert, data is inserted into the live table with a `ValidFrom` of "now" and a `ValidTo` of some high date (`9999-12-31 iirc). For updates, the record in the live table has its`ValidFrom`updated to "now" but there's also a record inserted into the history table with a`ValidFrom`of the previous value and a`ValidTo` of "now". On deletes, the record from the live table is deleted but the insert into the history table happens as described in the update scenario.

- For the inserts, you'll want to query your table with a predicate of `where ValidFrom >= '2020-02-14' and ValidFrom < '2020-02-15'` and no row exists in the history table (a left join by PK will work here).
- For the updates, you'll want to query the history table with a predicate of `where ValidTo >= '2020-02-14' and ValidTo < '2020-02-15'` and a corresponding record exists in the history table (an inner join by PK will work here)
- For any deletes, you'll want to query the history table with a predicate of `where ValidTo >= '2020-02-14' and ValidTo < '2020-02-15'` and no row exists in the live table (a left join by PK will work here).

Comment: Ok, I see it now, we have systemestart and systemdate, which was set up by the DBA team. And now I see the underlying history(Schema) table. now I see how to query the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Normal Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Applicants a
LEFT JOIN Users u on a.ApplicantID = u.UserID
ORDER BY StartTime;
```

Temporal Table Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Applicants 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2023-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
a
LEFT JOIN Users u on a.ApplicantID = u.UserID
ORDER BY StartTime;
```